# Using Variable for MS Chart Series names

Tags: vb.net

I'm using an MS Chart in my webpage and would like the series name to be the value of one of the data sources columns.

In my example, I would like to use the value in the field SalesYear to name the series instead of the static value Year1. How can I do that?

```
<asp:Chart
ID="chtPipelinePerformance"
runat="server" 
DataSourceID="dsPipelinePerformance"
>
<Series>
   <asp:Series
     Name="Year1"
     charttype="StackedColumn"
     color="RoyalBlue"
     XValueMember="SalesYear"
     YValueMembers="PipelineYear1"
     Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 10pt, style=Bold"
     >
   </asp:Series>
</Series>
</asp:Chart>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a Series in Codebehind:

```
Dim seriesName as String = "Myname"

chtPipelinePerformance.Series.Add(New Series(seriesName))
```

Databinding in Codebehind:

```
chtPipelinePerformance.DataBindTable(dataSource, xField)
```

You can databind your chart in codebind and do this to manipulate each series:

```
For Each s As Series In chtPipelinePerformance.Series
                s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn
                s.Name = s.XValueMember
            Next
```